# Can't remove index.php when in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I've just installed codeigniter, so if I type:

```
http://mysuperwebpage.comyr.com/projects/thebookshelf/index.php/welcome
```

It displays everythin as it should.

But I want to get rid of this `index.php` in the url, so you can access welcome controller without need to type `index.php` before `/welcome`:
`http://mysuperwebpage.comyr.com/projects/thebookshelf/welcome`

So i was following all needed steps which I found in same questions here on stack. What I've tried:

> **config.php:**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysuperwebpage.comyr.com/projects/thebookshelf/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

`.htaccess` file that is located in the root folder: `http://mysuperwebpage.comyr.com/projects/thebookshelf/.htaccess`

**Attempt #1** (not working)

> **.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Attempt #2** (not working)

> **.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Attempt #3** (not working)

> **.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

What am i missing or doing wrong? First time using .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i've found this information in the FAQ of the host:
[On this page](http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=16)

So what i had to do is add this lines before everything:

`RewriteBase /projects/thebookshelf/`

So now it's looking like this:

```
RewriteBase /projects/thebookshelf/

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I hope this will be helpful to people who use use virtual user home directory paths, as was in my case.

Comment: Thanks it also helped me

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you .htaccess file is under **the root** folder and not **the application** folder.
This is something you may not pay attention to.

Comment: Several days hitting my head against the wall, and turns out the solution was so obvious..... thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [CodeIgniter docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html), this is one way to do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: if i put it inside .htaccess it's not even allowing me to enter to the ```http://mysuperwebpage.comyr.com/projects/thebookshelf/``` but allows to access ```http://mysuperwebpage.comyr.com/projects/thebookshelf/index.php```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

For your **.htaccess** file (locate it in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /yourProjectName
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = "";
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside public_html dir open .htaccess and update below script

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```